# Using str_replace to replace a character and then 1 character after that

Tags: php, string, laravel

I have queried a Minecraft server and this is what it looks like
"§f§6§lMINE§b§lHEROES §7[1.7-1.14+] §b20% OFF SALE §e§lPRISON SERVER RESET §f- §9§lVIP OUT NOW!"

So I tried using str_replace to get rid of these `§`.

`str_replace('§', '', $server->name)`

Now it looks like this
"f6lMINEblHEROES 7[1.7-1.14+] b20% OFF SALE elPRISON SERVER RESET f- 9lVIP OUT NOW!"

It did get a lot of the jibberish out, but now there are random letters. These random letters are right after the `§` symbol. So I need to str_replace that symbol, as well as 1 character after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question you can try this:

```
$server->name = preg_replace('/§./', "", $server->name);
```

This will remove "§" with additional character as you ask.

But you might have to better understand "§" values and find custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the string by `§`, then implode them from index 1. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/nXhdc)

```
$arr = explode("§",$str);
$result = array_reduce($arr,function($a,$b){return $a . substr($b,1);},"");
```